# Ensure that box does not exceed a number of linebreaks

Tags: macros, conditionals, boxes

I have made a box that I do not want to exceed 22 lines. If it does it will overlap with some other text which is not desirable.

[image]

How can I ensure that the text will not have more than 22 lines? I had a couple solutions in mind:

- Add a counter that counts linebreaks and use it to ignore text after line 22.
- Specify a fixed height for the box so that line 23 will be outside the box and not be displayed over the gray text.

If possible, I'd like the solution to include:

1. Issuing an error that `mybox` has exceeded line limit of 22.
2. printing some text on line 22, like `etc.` to indicate that not all text was included. (this will be used to list contributors, so maybe something like `et. al.` would be preferable.)

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=13pt,a4paper,openany,parskip=half]{scrbook}

\RequirePackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand{\overlaytextbox}[3]{% \placetextbox{<horizontal pos>}{<vertical pos>}{<stuff>}
        \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
        \put(\LenToUnit{#1\paperwidth},%
        \LenToUnit{#2\paperheight}){\vtop{{\null}\parbox{0.3\textwidth}{#3}}}
  }%
}%
\newcommand{\mytextbox}[2][black]{%
    \overlaytextbox{0.05}{0.94}{% 0.65 og 0.94 for plassering til høyre
        \color{#1}
        \subsection*{Big TEXT \hfill \\ here \hfill}%
        \vspace{3mm}%
        \linespread{1.6}\selectfont
            {\itshape
            #2
            }%
    }%
}%

% These are the actual lenghts used in the document:
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength\topmargin{-58pt}                  
\setlength\headheight{27pt}                 
\setlength\headsep{25pt}                     
\setlength\marginparwidth{-20pt}             
\setlength\textwidth{\paperwidth - 52pt}     
\setlength\textheight{\paperheight - 112pt}  
\setlength\oddsidemargin{-45pt} 
\setlength\evensidemargin{-45pt} 

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
\begin{center}
    \lipsum[1-2]
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\mytextbox[red]{
line 1 can be this long foo baz\\
line 2 \\
line 3 \\
line 4 \\
line 5 \\
line 6 \\
line 7 \\
line 8 \\
line 9 \\
line 10 \\
line 11 \\
line 12 \\
line 13 \\
line 14 \\
line 15 \\
line 16 \\
line 17 \\
line 18 \\
line 19 \\
line 20 \\
line 21 \\
line 22 \\
}

\overlaytextbox{0.05}{0.2}{
{\color{gray}\centering
foo baz baa \\
boo baz baa \\
more text under here...
}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: so you are only interested in manual line breaks with `\\ ` (which makes counting lines trivial) not automatic line breaks (much harder or not in general possible, although you can give an error if the paragraph generates too many lines, it is hard to adjust the text for automatic linebreaking)?

Comment: Yes @DavidCarlisle

Comment: How do you count manual line breaks @DavidCarlisle ? My guess would be some if statement that says ``if \\ --> \stepcounter{ }`` ?

Comment: locally `\def\\{\stepcounter{mycount}\par}`